# How to make ListView of Music Library Universal Windows c#?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I want to make ListView has my music library and its Name, Artist, Album, Album Cover and I do it by make Class called it MusicLibs.cs and i write this code 
in MusicLibs.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;

 namespace App29
 {
   class MusicLib
   {
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public string MusicPath{ get; set; }
    public BitmapImage AlbumCover { get; set; }

 }
}
```

and i write this in MainPage.xaml :

```
<Page
x:Class="App29.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App29"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView Name="mylist" ItemsSource="{x:Bind MusicList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Tapped="StackPanel_Tapped" >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Album}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding AlbumCover}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <MediaElement Name="mymediaelememt" Source="{Binding MusicPath}"/>

</Grid>
```

and i write this in MainPage.xaml.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.FileProperties;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

   namespace App29
 {
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    private ObservableCollection<MusicLib> MusicList = new ObservableCollection<MusicLib>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        StorageFolder musicLib = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
        var files = await musicLib.GetFilesAsync();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            StorageItemThumbnail currentThumb = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.MusicView, 200, ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);
            var albumCover = new BitmapImage();
            albumCover.SetSource(currentThumb);

            var musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
            var musicname = musicProperties.Title;
            var musicdur = musicProperties.Duration;

            var artist = musicProperties.Artist;
            if (artist == "")
            {
                artist = "Artista desconocido";
            }

            var album = musicProperties.Album;
            if (album == "")
            {
                album = "Unkown";
            }
            MusicList.Add(new MusicLib
            {
                FileName = musicname,
                Artist = artist,
                Album = album,
                Duration = musicdur,
                AlbumCover = albumCover,
                MusicPath = file.Path
            });

        }
    }

    private void StackPanel_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }


}
```

}

and it works fine but i want it to play selected music when i click it how i do that ???

Comment: set the `SelectedValuePath` to be the file path, then use `Process.Start(myList.SelectedValue)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a new SelectionChanged event for the ListView:

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView view = (ListView)sender;
        //Get Selected Item
        MusicLib song = view.SelectedItem as MusicLib;
        string path = song.MusicPath;

        //code to play song from song.MusicPath
        MediaElement player = new MediaElement();
        player.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(path));

        player.Play();
        //can then control the playback of the song through the player object then
    }
```

Then attach it to your ListView in the constructor for the page insted of the tapped event:

```
mylist.SelectionChanged += ListView_SelectionChanged;
```

Edit 1: 
Added playing of the song from source string

Comment: Did you need help playing the song as well from the path?

Answer (score 0):

To use ListView as clickable list, you should use the `ItemClick` event.

**XAML:**

```
<ListView SelectionMode="None"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick"
          >
```

**C#:**

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    MusicLib clicked = (MusicLib)e.ClickedItem;
    // Playing the file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should use the Marian's methods or @Kenny methods to get the item that the user click and then you should use the `MediaPlayer` that help you to play the music and give it a name,for example name it "Media" .After doing that,you can set `Meia.Source` to the Music that the user selected.

```
 Meia.Source=MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(song.MusicPath));
 Media.Play();
```

More info about `MediaPlayer` ,goto https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/play-audio-and-video-with-mediaplayer